# DC Motor bridge driver L298N. Why separate the tracks after R sense resistors from GND plane?

Tags: pcb-design, l298

The [L298N](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/motor-drivers/brushed-dc-motor-drivers/l298.html) datasheet says:

> The sense resistor, not of a wire wound type, must be grounded near
>   the negative pole of Vs that must be near the GND pin of the I.C.

[image: design layout example]
why not in common GND plane?
If I connect resistors to the common ground, how does this affect the operation of the device?
Thx.

Comment: Make it easy for your readers. Include a datasheet link and page or figure reference so we can check the context. Also explain what an L298N is. e.g., Audio amplifier, or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [L289 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf) Application Instructions - Suggestions, on page 7, says:

> The sense resistor, not of a wire wound type, must
>   be grounded near the negative pole of Vs that must
>   be near the GND pin of the I.C.

This ensures that the voltage measured on the sense inputs is all due to the current on that output and not any other currents running through the ground plane causing small additional voltage lifts which would cause errors in the current control.